# Auto lookup feature using bootstrap (Plunker Attached)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

here is the plunker- http://plnkr.co/edit/nMozzczMrbXJPfcps0A2?p=preview

If you can notice, i have added the below css class to auto lookup feature.

```
 .dropdown-menu {
background-color:white;
overflow:scroll;
height:300px;
}
```

I donot mention this class in html anywhere. the bootstrap automatically takes this css class and applied it to my dropdown.

I donot want this to happen. how do i assign a new class and have the same properties assigned to the dropdown-menu which pops up at the plunker if we type any alphabet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a new CSS class by overriding drop down template:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap'])
  .run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
     $templateCache.put("template/typeahead/typeahead-popup.html",
       "<ul class=\"dropdown-menu your-custom-class\" ng-show=\"isOpen() && !moveInProgress\" ng-style=\"{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}\" style=\"display: block;\" role=\"listbox\" aria-hidden=\"{{!isOpen()}}\">\n" +
       "  <li ng-repeat=\"match in matches track by $index\" ng-class=\"{active: isActive($index) }\" ng-mouseenter=\"selectActive($index)\" ng-click=\"selectMatch($index)\" role=\"option\" id=\"{{::match.id}}\">\n" +
       "    <div uib-typeahead-match index=\"$index\" match=\"match\" query=\"query\" template-url=\"templateUrl\"></div>\n" +
       "  </li>\n" +
       "</ul>\n" +
       "");
}]);
```

in this example I added *your-custom-class* class next to the *dropdown-menu* class, and added CSS rule - background: red

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iMKsB5TULDYRcyfoYSek?p=preview